# xml regular expression/regex OR operator

Tags: xml, regex, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to use a regex to read through my document to identify currency types whether they're `$`, `£` or a `€`. The regex I've created doesn't seem to work, somebody please advise me what it should be. I'd really appreciate the help:

The regex I've created `("\$|£|€]")`is in a simpleType within my XSD file used for validating a document. The code is show after the colon:

```
<xs:simpleType name="currencyType">
  <xs:restriction base="utf8-string">
    <xs:length value="1" />
  <xs:pattern value="[\$|£|€]"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't use the or (|) operator in a character set:

```
[$£€]
```

If you use the or operator, then you don't use a set:

```
(\$|£|€)
```

Comment: Thanks I've just figured it out a second ago using: ([\$|£|€])".
Have tested this too and it works, is there a major difference between the 2?

Comment: Just tried your version, doesn't seem to work. None the less I really appreciate the help and the quick response. Thank you!!

Comment: @NazHaque: Putting parentheses around the set makes no sense. Having the `|` in the set will make it accept "|" as a valid currency.

Comment: @NazHaque: Whenever you're faced with a choice between an alternation and a character class with no compelling reason to choose one over the other, go with the character class.  It's more readable, more efficient, and much less prone to catastrophic backtracking scenarios.